# How do I connect a 240v compressor with only black and white wires?

Tags: electrical, 240v, compressor

[image]
I got a new air compressor that says 240 volt only but it only has a black and white wire please help.[image]

Comment: What are you trying to hook it up to?

Comment: What does the plug look like? Can you either post a photo or identify it using [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector#/media/File:NEMA_simplified_pins.svg)?

Comment: Definitely need more info.

Comment: It has no plug and hard line to the breaker

Comment: Not all white wires are neutral, and not all neutrals are white.

Answer (score 2):

Get some red electrical tape and wrap it around the white wire, this will make the wiring more obvious to you.  It is not properly color-coded because they are using common off-the-shelf 3-wire cordage, which is manufactured as black/white/green. It's legal to omit the marking on machinery, but it's required in wiring that's part of your house (often omitted there too).

You will need 240V electrical service.  If you connect it via cord and plug, you will need a **NEMA 6** plug and a NEMA 6 receptacle.  You can also use a NEMA 14 plug and receptacle; in that case you will not hook up neutral on the plug.

If you are doing brand-new wiring for this, it may be best to use /3 cable and bring along a neutral *in the wiring* to the outlet point.  You would not use the neutral, but it would be installed and ready for use for some future application.

Comment: It should be noted that altering the color of the wire is legal in this case because you are using pre-manufactured cabling, where it's expected that you will not have access to custom colors.  If you use conduit and wires, you will need properly colored wire unless the wire is a much larger size than you have here.

Comment: @ChrisParker It is allowed because he is re-marking a neutral to a hot.  That is allowed even in conduit.  You cannot remark a wire to neutral or ground.  You also cannot remark a ground to anything else. So neutral->hot is the only remark allowed.

Answer (score -2):

Each leg is 120 Volt. There is no common leg.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/63017)

Comment: Perhaps the answer is vague, but it does answer the question, IMHO.

Comment: While the information provided is correct, it doesn't really do anything to help the asker solve the problem (which is admittedly vauge; the question should probably be closed)

Comment: Thanks for the info... I thought so but the white wire though me off...lol